# Google Trends fetchComponent not returning recent search volume

Tags: api, search, google-trends

URL example: [San Francisco Giants previous 12 months search volume](https://trends.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en&q=San%20Francisco%20Giants&date=today%2012-m&cmpt=q&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=330)

The last month of data is absent. Does anyone know of a different date/time parameter (besides `&date=today+12-m`) to get the full data for the last year?

[The official website has the last month's data.](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=San%20Francisco%20Giants)

I know it's an undocumented 'API' of sorts, but any assistance would be appreciated.

Otherwise, is there an easier alternative to work with?

Thanks again!